# How to get timestamp and do maths on it without caring about the day?

Tags: perl

I am trying to do some maths with timestamps (or rather without timestamps, but I think I need to use timestamps) in Perl, which is not a language I am very familiar with. I'm particularly unfamiliar with date an time functions of it.

Basically I have a function that takes 5 integers as arguments.

```
sub calculateEndTime {
    my ($hour, $minute, $second, $roundingInterval ,$buffer)
    ...
}
```

The maths I want to do is probably irrelevant but is simply:

1. Round the minutes to the nearest $roundingInterval. E.g if it's 15, round to the nearest quarter hour. I used the below to do it.

```
    my $nearestInterval = round($minute / $roundingInterval) * $roundingInterval;
    $hour = $hour + 1 if $nearestInterval == 60; #That's gonna screw up future calculations
    $nearestInterval = 0 if $nearestInterval == 60;
```

2. If the given hour, minute, second is within `$buffer` minutes (default 5 minutes) either side of the rounded time, return the initial `($hour, $minute, $second)`.

This is where it kind of fell apart, I need a timestamp to check this, manually is going to be a pain to check if hours tick over etc. So how do I create a timestamp from just an hour, minute and second when I don't care about the date? Just give it the current date or some other placeholder?

Comment: If they're timestamps, then you need to date and time zone or else you can get incorrect calculations and timestamps that don't exist. But maybe they're just durations? if so, easier to work with just seconds rather than hour+minutes+seconds

Comment: @ikegami yeah that would be my question I guess. I don't have dates, so what's the best way to get hours, minutes and seconds into a format I can do math with?

Comment: Like I said, work with just seconds instead of three quantities in different units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with just seconds. Then all you need is

```perl
my $rounded = round( $time / $internal ) * $interval;

if ( abs( $rounded - $time ) < $buffer ) {
   $rounded = $time;
}
```

---

```perl
sub to_time {
   my $hours   = shift;
   my $minutes = shift;
   my $seconds = shift;

   my $time = ( $hour * 60 + $minutes ) * 60 + $seconds;

   return $time;
}

sub from_time {
   my $time = shift;

   my $seconds = $time % 60;  $time = ( $time - $seconds ) / 60;
   my $minutes = $time % 60;  $time = ( $time - $minutes ) / 60;
   my $hours   = $time;

   return ( $hours, $minutes, $seconds );
}

sub calculate_end_time {
   my ( $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $interval, $buffer ) = @_;

   my $time = to_time( $hours, $minutes, $seconds );

   $interval *= 60;
   $buffer   *= 60;

   my $rounded = round( $time / $internal ) * $interval;

   if ( abs( $rounded - $time ) < $buffer ) {
      $rounded = $time;
   }

   return from_time( $rounded );
}
```